# Running sqoop on remote client machine

Tags: java, hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

I am trying to run sqoop import from a client machine using java. I'll be following sqoop client api file.

I had the following query

1. The machine from which I am running the client java class need not have hadoop installed on it
2. I have cloudera 5.5.1 installed on this system and it has sqoop installed, can I make use of it

Please pardon me if I am asking silly questions. I have implemented sqoop from cli but struggling with remote access

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop 2 is distributed as two separate packages: a client package (sqoop2-client) and a server package (sqoop2-server). Install the server package on one node in the cluster; because the Sqoop 2 server acts as a MapReduce client this node must have Hadoop installed and configured.

Install the client package on each node that will act as a client. A Sqoop 2 client will always connect to the Sqoop 2 server to perform any actions, so Hadoop does not need to be installed on the client nodes.

So the answer to your questions are below-

**question 1:** Client is not acting as a mapreduce client and thus you do not need to install Hadoop on nodes that will act only as a Sqoop client.

**question2:** As long as it's the client version of sqoop I think yes you can use it.